# MapReduce and SQL GROUP BY

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, group-by, mapreduce

I have been trying to understand the basics of MapReduce in MongoDB and even after implementing it, I'm not sure how exactly it is different from SQL's GROUP BY or even Mongo's own GROUP BY. In SQL server, a GROUP BY can be done by stream or hash aggregate. Isn't MapReduce similar to hash aggregate, just over a large number of servers?

I have been reading at places that MR for MongoDB is to be run as a background process since it is a "heavy operation". Given that the data is sharded, wouldn't a GROUP BY be equally "heavy"? That said, I'm only trying to compare those type of operations that are possible to be implemented both as an MR job or using GROUP BY query.

Is there something that GROUP BY can't do and only MR can do?

Also, Hadoop seems to be very good at MR (This is only what I have read..I have never worked on Hadoop). How's Hadoop's MR different from that of Mongo?

I'm confused. Kindly help or guide me to a good tutorial that explains the need of MapReduce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you get by using MR is speed. GROUP BY is a slow operation in SQL and MR is even slower in MongoDB. But what you do is that you create new collections and iterate over them in real time. This is very good when you have large amounts of data and want to be able to iterate over it in real time.

In the project I'm working on there is a Python script running in the background (cron job) doing different map/reduces once per day. Instead of iterating over large tables with SQL group by, we iterate once with MR and then iterate fast on the new collections created.

I have no experience in Hadoop. So I'm sorry I can't fill you in there.

Tutorial:
http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial/

**EDIT:**

Here you may see an entire translation of an SQL query to a MongoDB Map/Reduce:
[image: GROUP BY to MongoDB Map/Reduce]
It's taken from: http://rickosborne.org/download/SQL-to-MongoDB.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the insight..Am I then correct in thinking that MapReduce is basically a 'philosophy' of aggregation and could be followed in SQL server as well, if we could generate new tables on the fly and store intermediate MR results into them?

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if it did answer your question or at least vote up! :)

Comment: Yes indeed! Thanks :) However, the nearly perfect mapping between MySQL GROUP BY and MapReduce makes me think they have equal powers, unless the real-time creation of those intermediate collections is really happening behind the scenes..I'm guessing all that is helpful when data is avaiable on varous shards and MR job has to be run over and over on the intermediate results to get the final results..which won't happen in SQL server, where you don't store your intermediate results..

Comment: Well, I'm not totally sure if I follow but what I meant was that MySQL GROUP BY is actually a faster operation than Map/Reduce in MongoDB but if you have 50.000 users querying a MySQL GROUP BY it will be a lot slower than creating new collections once every 30 sec in MongoDB. You can, however, use Map/Reduce in a query and make MongoDB just use the new collections temporary and just for that specific request.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of folk use MongoDB as the data storage and Hadoop for processing as there's connector between the two. Each MongoDB node can handle multiple Hadoop nodes reading into it.  As a note, I'd recommend is separating mongo and Hadoop nodes for memory.

In case you don't have them, here's some documents for you

- [Quick Start](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Quick+Start)
- [Scenarios (including Map-Reduce)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Scenarios)
- [The Interconnector](http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/MongoDB+Hadoop+Connector.html)
- [Streaming](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/24610529795/hadoop-streaming-support-for-mongodb)

One other thing that might be worth looking at is the new [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) coming out in [2.2](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.2+Release+Notes). Here's [chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Aggregation+Framework+Mapping+Chart) equating the operations in SQL with those in the MongoDB aggregation framework.

Comment: Yes, upvoted :) Thanks again; You gave me an altogether new branch to explore!